# How to add custom radio group programmatically

Tags: android, radio-group

I am trying to programmatically add a radio group to my android application using a custom radio group (from https://github.com/Kaopiz/android-segmented-control).

I can create the group with

```
SegmentedGroup rg = new SegmentedGroup(this)
```

but when I try to add attributes with

```
SegmentedGroup rg = new SegmentedGroup (this, R.attr.myCustomStyle)
```

I get the following error "int cannot be converted to AttributeSet".

To my understanding, this object should accept an attribute set... what am I not getting? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

The constructor with AttributeSet is used internally when a view is inflated from XML.
You can use a custom view in XML just like any built-in view by specifying it's full name:

```
<info.hoang8f.android.segmented.SegmentedGroup
    android:id="@+id/custom_radio_group"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
</info.hoang8f.android.segmented.SegmentedGroup>
```

If you create the view manually by calling a constructor, you should use the one that takes just a context and then manipulate the object as you wish. It has various getter and setter methods that should allow you to set the same attributes as in xml.

Comment: I am able to modify the segmented group with such setters as   rg.setPadding(50,50,10,10);  ...but unfortunately the custom SegmentedGroup doesn't have a setter for border width... that's why I'm trying to set it via xml. apologies if I'm missing something basic, mostly used to iOS development